# C# Multidimensional Arrays in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm converting a C# class to C++ and i'm currently blocked by the following part:

```
public class Perlin
{
    const int B = 0x100;
    const int BM = 0xff;
    const int N = 0x1000;

    int[] p = new int[B + B + 2];
    float[,] g3 = new float [B + B + 2 , 3];
    float[,] g2 = new float[B + B + 2,2];
    float[] g1 = new float[B + B + 2];
}
```

I have no idea on how to express those multidimensional arrays in C++. Can anyone help? :)

Comment: You'd have to create multidimensional arrays using pointers. Basically you create the first dimension with `new` and then iterate over it with `new` for each cell or element.

Comment: @pandoragami _"You'd have to create multidimensional arrays using pointers"_ Huh?? That's the worst choice.

Comment: Show me another way  @πάντα ῥεῖ.

Comment: 2D arrays : type[][], 3D arrays: type[][][]

Comment: A proper way to create variable sized multidimentional arrays would be something like `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` (for 2D) for example.

Comment: Right, but he's using `new` in C#, I thought he wanted the equivalent.

Comment: @pandoragami ^ Done!

Comment: @pandoragami We avoid `new` and `delete` in proper c++ code even more than pest and cholera.

Comment: @Vivick ^^ That's also true for raw c-style arrays.

Comment: Do you see why i created the question now, @CamiloTerevinto? It's not as simple as you think. It would be nice if you were less condescending.

Comment: If the 2D array is rectangular and dynamic, there are also ways (sometimes better) to do it with a 1D array mapped to look like a 2D array with a wrapper class that overloads the `operator()`.

Comment: @user4581301 Not much gain over `std::array`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed. Should be no gain over `std::array`, but it doesn't need to be sized at compile time. Versus it's competition in the dynamic allocation world, it's usually the winner.

Comment: @user4581301 In this case OP asks for fixed dimensions. I agree with you regarding the nested `std::vector`'s though. Feel free to write another answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto *It's not as simple as you think.* -- It is simple to an experienced C++ programmer  **if** that C# syntax was explained to us instead of just posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Or for people who are familiar with both languages ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent for fixed dimensioned multidimensional arrays in c++ is the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container class:

```
class Perlin
{
    static constexpr int B = 0x100;
    static constexpr int BM = 0xff;
    static constexpr int N = 0x1000;

    std::array<int,B + B + 2> p;
    std::array<std::array<float,B + B + 2>,3> g3;
    std::array<std::array<float,B + B + 2>,2> g2;
    std::array<float,B + B + 2> g1;
};
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db378c14e3392efc)

Comment: Why not static constexpr?

Comment: @vinnylinux In fact, you're right. It [doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dc0c96795640fac) without `static`.

Comment: With std::array, how would you write this? `g2[i,j] = (float)(rnd.Next(B + B) - B) / B;`

Comment: @vinnylinux Like this probably: `g2[i][j] = (float)(rnd.Next(B + B) - B) / B;`

Comment: @vinnylinux Immer gerne, bitte. :)